# Callback within callback in Android?

Tags: android, parsefacebookutils

I was trying to have a callback within a callback process. Is this possible for Android? I know it has something to do with the Main Thread, but I don't know about a good fix to it as I was a total beginner in making Android apps.

Is there a way to put these processes in different threads in Android?

Help is very much appreciated!

Note: Imports are all included and accounted for.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = LoginFragment.class.getSimpleName();

@InjectView(R.id.emailField) EditText mEmailField;
@InjectView(R.id.passwordField) EditText mPassword;
@InjectView(R.id.loginButton) Button mLoginButton;
@InjectView(R.id.signupButton) Button mSignupButton;

//Facebook CallbackManager

private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

//Facebook Callback

/* This is the first callback */

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        if(profile != null) {

            /* This is the second callback within the first callback */

            ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(accessToken, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        //Create a dialog to remind the user there was something wrong.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

//Empty constructor, for fragments.
public LoginFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Facebook Callback Manager. See above.
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, myFragmentView);

    //Facebook button
    LoginButton fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends", "email"));
    fbLoginButton.setFragment(this);
    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
    return myFragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Get Facebook Fragment activity result after callback.
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@OnClick(R.id.loginButton) void loginUser() {
    String username = mEmailField.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oops. Login details incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was an error trying to log in your account. Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.signupButton) void toSignup() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the error code are as follows:

```
    07-15 12:14:47.128  26515-26566/com.vonderphil.doorbell E/DataScheduler﹕ isDataSchedulerEnabled():false
    07-15 12:14:55.478  26515-26515/com.vonderphil.doorbell E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vonderphil.doorbell, PID: 26515
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.parse.Parse.callbackOnMainThreadAsync
            at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:149)
            at com.vonderphil.doorbell.fragments.LoginFragment$1.onSuccess(LoginFragment.java:77)
            at com.vonderphil.doorbell.fragments.LoginFragment$1.onSuccess(LoginFragment.java:69)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:508)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:192)
            at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:140)
            at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
            at com.vonderphil.doorbell.fragments.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:162)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:163)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5467)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3378)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3425)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @frankeizz09 any idea how to query from multiple tables having pointers and array of pointers in parse and get objects from pointers

Comment: @Erum hi! Sorry, I have no idea on how to query multiple tables and pointers stuff. :( A total beginner here.

Comment: Callback within a callback will drive you to the callback hell soon. Read more about RxJava, RxAndroid and try to transform your approach into Functional Reactive Programming solution.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen Thanks for that info! I'll dig deep into that now. I know something's wrong with having a callback inception and never knew about reactive programming at all. :)